# React Hooks: init local state after data is fetched

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Given a simple checkbox component, I want to set "checked" once after some asyn data fetching is done and a condition is met.

How do I modify the following example to achieve this? Right now, "checked" cant be set "false" because the condition is always met and therefore is always "true".

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const asyncFetch = () => "blub";

export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  const callFromSpace = asyncFetch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (callFromSpace === "blub") {
      setChecked(true);
    }
  }, [checked, callFromSpace]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{callFromSpace}</p>

      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={(e) => setChecked(e.target.checked)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

EDIT: "callFromSpace" is also needed elsewhere in the component, so cant be encapsulated inside the "useEffect".

Comment: You need to create a variable inside useEffect something like isDataFetching on false and after your async func when it's ok set this to true

Comment: put asyncFetch in the didmount hook useEffect(()=>{},[])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (callFromSpace === "blub") {
    setChecked(true);
  }
}, [callFromSpace]); // 'checked' should be excluded.
```

When you update `checked` it would effect `useEffect()` eventually `setChecked(true)` called again...

so, you should exclude `checked` on the dependency of `useEffect()`.

Comment: This would work but leaves me with the "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency" warning. So I guess its somehow bad practice?

Comment: @ynotu. I don't think so. And I guess what you see the warning is about `setChecked`, not `checked`.

Comment: Yeah you are right, the example I posted doesnt need the "checked" dependency. The original code used it though. But I restructured the code and Im able to remove it now, so it works as in the example given, thanx kyun!

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to do it would be put yout async function inside the `Effect`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const asyncFetch = () => "blub";

export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [tryCheck, setTryCheck] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFromSpace = async () => {
        const response = await asyncFetch();
        if (callFromSpace === "blub") {
            setChecked(true);
        }
    }
    if(tryCheck){
       fetchFromSpace();
    }
  }, [tryCheck]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={(e) => setTryCheck(e.target.checked)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to only do the check once, and have no dependency for it as it seems to be the case, run your useEffect only once and call your async function directly inside of it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const asyncFetch = async () => "blub"; // This function need to return a promise

export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    asyncFetch().then(response => {
        if (callFromSpace === "blub") {
            setChecked(true); // Will update your state as soon as your request returns
        }
    });
  }, []); // No dependency, will only run once

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={(e) => setChecked(e.target.checked)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What if I need the return of the asyncFetch for rendering?